Не могу запустить код C++ в vs code на linux
Всем привет!


Подозреваю что не настроен компилятор. Но как настроить не знаю. Обыскал весь РУ инет. Четкого решения проблемы нет.
Помогите пожалуйста!
launch.json
{
  // Используйте IntelliSense, чтобы узнать о возможных атрибутах.
  // Наведите указатель мыши, чтобы просмотреть описания существующих атрибутов.
  // Для получения дополнительной информации посетите: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": []
}

tasks.json
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: gcc сборка активного файла",
      "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
      "args": [
        "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "Задача создана отладчиком."
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}


С компилятором все в порядке, сэр. Ваш код не компилируется из-за ошибки в коде, который вы упорно не показываете. А раз не компилируется, то и исполняемый файл не находит для запуска.

Действительно... прошу прощения за столь глупый пост, я просто новичек в плюсах) =D

Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос исходный код (текстом!), файл launch.json, файл tasks.json. Чтобы редактировать, нажмите под вопросом кнопку "Править".

Понял, принял, обработал!

Код добавьте, код! И ошибку компиляции.

Этот launch.json и скриншот от разных проектов. В tasks.json вы выполнили только компиляцию, но не линковку.  И код вы так и не добавили.
